# Why do all images resulting by DeepLabV3+ become black only?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, segmentation-fault, semantic-segmentation, deeplab

I tried semantic segmentation with the DeepLab v3+ but I got results all black out.

I deleted the original file and put original data in ImageSets/,JPEGImages/ and SegmentationClass/ corresponding to each.

I prepared SegmentationClassRaw image according to the rule of PASCAL VOC 2012 color.

And I edited build_voc2012_data.py and segmentation_dataset.py

[build_voc2012_data.py]

```
FLAGS = tf.app.flags.FLAGS

tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('image_folder',
                           './VOCdevkit/VOC2012/JPEGImages',
                           'Folder containing images.')

tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string(
    'semantic_segmentation_folder',
    './VOCdevkit/VOC2012/SegmentationClassRaw',
    'Folder containing semantic segmentation annotations.')

tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string(
    'list_folder',
    './VOCdevkit/VOC2012/ImageSets/Segmentation',
    'Folder containing lists for training and validation')

tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string(
    'output_dir',
    './tfrecord',
    'Path to save converted SSTable of TensorFlow examples.')


_NUM_SHARDS = 4

# add -->>
FLAGS.image_folder = "./pascal_voc_seg/VOCdevkit/VOC2012/JPEGImages"
FLAGS.semantic_segmentation_folder = "./pascal_voc_seg/VOCdevkit/VOC2012/SegmentationClassRaw"
FLAGS.list_folder = "./pascal_voc_seg/VOCdevkit/VOC2012/ImageSets/Segmentation"
FLAGS.image_format = "png"
FLAGS.output_dir = "./pascal_voc_seg/tfrecord"
# add --<<
```

[segmentation_dataset.pu]

```
# add kani 20181115 -->>
_ORIGINAL_INFORMATION = DatasetDescriptor(
    splits_to_sizes={
        'train': 10,
        'trainval': 2,
        'val': 2,
    },
    num_classes=5,
    ignore_label=255,
)
#add kani 20181115 --<<

# mod kani 20181115 -->>
# _DATASETS_INFORMATION = {
#     'cityscapes': _CITYSCAPES_INFORMATION,
#     'pascal_voc_seg': _PASCAL_VOC_SEG_INFORMATION,
#     'ade20k': _ADE20K_INFORMATION,
# }

_DATASETS_INFORMATION = {
    'cityscapes': _CITYSCAPES_INFORMATION,
    'pascal_voc_seg': _PASCAL_VOC_SEG_INFORMATION,
    'ade20k': _ADE20K_INFORMATION,
    'original': _ORIGINAL_INFORMATION,
}
# mod kani 20181115 --<<
```

I run train.py and vis.py like this.

[train.py command]

```
python train.py   --logtostderr   --train_split=trainval   --model_variant=xception_65   --atrous_rates=3   --atrous_rates=6   --atrous_rates=9   --output_stride=32   --decoder_output_stride=4   --train_crop_size=512   --train_crop_size=512   --train_batch_size=2   --training_number_of_steps=6000   --fine_tune_batch_norm=false   --tf_initial_checkpoint="./datasets/pascal_voc_seg/init_models/deeplabv3_pascal_train_aug/model.ckpt"  --train_logdir="./datasets/pascal_voc_seg/exp/train_on_trainval_set/train"  --dataset_dir="./datasets/pascal_voc_seg/tfrecord" --dataset=original
```

[vis.py command]

```
python vis.py   --logtostderr   --vis_split="val"   --model_variant="xception_65"   --atrous_rates=6   --atrous_rates=12   --atrous_rates=18   --output_stride=16   --decoder_output_stride=4   --vis_crop_size=513   --vis_crop_size=513   --checkpoint_dir="./datasets/pascal_voc_seg/exp/train_on_trainval_set/train"   --vis_logdir="./datasets/pascal_voc_seg/exp/train_on_trainval_set/vis"  --dataset_dir="./datasets/pascal_voc_seg/tfrecord"   --max_number_of_iterations=1   --dataset=original   --max_resize_value=512   --min_resize_value=128
```

Both ended without a problem but I confirmed pictures in `datasets/pascal_voc_seg/exp/train_on_trainval_set/vis/raw_segmentation_results/`, these are black out all. why?

Is this because of train data is bigger than 512x512?
(Train data size is so big: about 15000x13500)

[structure my directory]

```
/tmp/models/research/deeplab  
-README.md  
-common.py  
-datasets/  
--__init__.py  
--build_data.py  
--convert_cityscapes.sh  
--pascal_voc_seg/  
---VOCdevkit/  
----VOC2012/  
-----Annotations/  
-----ImageSets/  
-----JPEGImages/  
-----SegmentationClass/  
-----SegmentationObject/  
---VOCtrainval_11-May-2012.tar  
---exp/  
----train_on_trainval_set/  
-----train/  
------train.py  
-----vis/  
------vis.py  
---init_models/  
----deeplabv3_pascal_train_aug/  
-----frozen_inference_graph.pb  
-----model.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001  
-----model.ckpt.index  
---tfrecord/  
----build_voc_2012.py  
--__pycache__  
--build_data.pyc  
--download_and_convert_ade20k.sh  
--remove_gt_colormap.py  
--build_ade20k_data.py  
--build_voc2012_data.py  
--download_and_convert_voc2012.sh  
--segmentation_dataset.py  
--build_cityscapes_data.py  
--build_voc2012_data.py.org  
-export_model.py  
-local_test.sh  
-model_test.py  
-utils/  
-__init__.py  
-common_test.py  
-deeplab_demo.ipynb  
-g3doc/  
-local_test_mobilenetv2.sh  
-train.py  
-vis.py  
-__pycache__  
-core/  
-eval.py  
-input_preprocess.py  
-model.py  
-train.py.bk
```

Comment: Are you sure the image size used for training is 15000x13500? As per my experience, an image of this much size will take a lot of computation time. And how many such images did you use to train the network?

Comment: Hey @y_kani, I can help you if you would tell me for which dataset are you trying to perform semantic segmentation?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are not trying to use the model for some exotic classes, my guess is that the images are not actually all black. This is due to the fact that you are looking at the raw segmentation results. The output should have just a single color channel, and with your 5 classes it may appear as all black. A simple test would be to read the output PNG as a numpy array and then check the values of the image with `np.unique`. If indeed the result of all PNG files amounts to just `0`, then the reason you are seeing black images might be different.

Note that I am making the assumption above because you are using very little training data.